# How would you solve this ODE, $s(s-4){y}-{(s-4){\sin 2x}}=y''$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone have any ideas? Factoring out the $(s-4)$ doesn't seem to help and I can't easily get an auxiliary equation.

Comment: Is $y$ a function of both $x$ and $s$, or is $s$ to be treated as a constant?

Comment: look up driven harmonic oscillator, which this is the equation of.

Answer (score 0):

First step: solve a homogenous equation, obtain two linearly independent solutions.

Second step: use the method of variation of arbitrary constant to find a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

At first ou solve the homogenous differential equation: $s(s-4)y_h=y_h''$. To find a particulary solution you can use the Variation of constant method: You have some constants in your homogenous solution; now you make These constant dependent on $x$. Substitute this new Ansatz into your ODE and simplify. Then you obtain a differential equation for your "varied constants". Your complete solution is given by $y=y_h+y_p$ where $y_p$ is your solution with "varied constants".